# animation on hidden div when showing

Tags: html, css, hover

I am hiding a div with the class `.text` with

```
 div.text {
    visibility:hidden;
 }
```

This div is surrounded by another div with the class `.col3`

```
<div class="col3">
   <div class="image-box">
      <div class="text"> test </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want the visibility to change to "`visible`" when I hover over `.col3`

I tried

```
.col3:hover > div.text {
   visibility:visible;
}
```

So this works, and makes the div visible when I hover the surrounding div.

How do I animate (or at least slow down , fade in) the div?

Comment: You need css3 or javascript, is it ok to use them ?

Comment: css3 preferred , but yes, both are accepted

Comment: Let me clear one thing up, i need to use display:hidden; display:block;

Comment: because i want the divs below it to either move down or up depending on hoverstate

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and you can take the following code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".col3").hover(function()
    {
        // fading in (500 = animation time in ms)
        $("div.text").css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}, 500).animate({opacity:         1.0});
    }, function()
    {
        // hover out function -> fading out
        $("div.text").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 500, function()
        {
            // callback function -> setting visibility back to hidden
            $(this).css({visibility: "hidden"})
        });
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KLsGt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this work easily with `jquery` :

HTML:

```
<div class="col3">
   <div class="image-box">
      <div class="text"> test </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
    display:none;
 }
```

Jquery:

```
 $('.col3').hover(function(){
        $('.text').fadeOut(1000);
        $('.text').fadeIn( 1000 );
    }, function() {
     $('.text').css('display', 'none');
  }
);
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/hVaMN/1/)